# Multiple variables into option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form with some options in it which are disabled and greyed out by default.

```
<select name="template" id="template" size="1" >
    <option disabled selected value="1" name="1" id="1" class="bold-option">Mango</option>
    <option class="select1"></option>
    <option disabled selected value="2" class="bold-option" >Apple</option>
    <option disabled selected value="3" class="bold-option">Pineapple</option>
    <option disabled selected value="4" class="bold-option">Brocolli</option>
    <option disabled selected value="5" class="bold-option">Peach</option>
    <option disabled selected value="6" class="bold-option">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

The idea behind it is that i want multiple variables which are defined by JQuery are getting imported into the select1 option for example, so the items that are linked to Select1 are listed below Mango.

I've made a var :

```
var issueTemplates = [ 
  {'subject': 'This is a mango'}
];
```

Now i want to add this variable into the Option value beneath (or linked) to the Mango option within the select.  I've looked into the append function but i cant seem to figure out how to get this straight.

I've made a select request in jquery which adds the subject in the dropdown form. But i want to have it beneath the Mango option..

This is de code

```
issueTemplates.forEach(function(item, idx) {       
 $("select[id='template']").append('<option value="' + idx + '">' + item.subject + '</option>');
```

Comment: It's really not very clear what you want.  Can you post an example of the `select` element once the additional variables have been added?

Comment: added the jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.  If you have an array of additional options, you can iterate through the select element and load by index -1.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fruit = ['mango', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'brocolli', 'peach', 'strawberry']
  $('#template option').each(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    $(this).after('<Option val = ' + val + '>This is a ' + fruit[val - 1] + '</option>');
  });
  console.log($('#template option'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="template" id="template" size="1">
  <option disabled selected value="1" name="1" id="1" class="bold-option">Mango</option>
  <option disabled selected value="2" class="bold-option">Apple</option>
  <option disabled selected value="3" class="bold-option">Pineapple</option>
  <option disabled selected value="4" class="bold-option">Brocolli</option>
  <option disabled selected value="5" class="bold-option">Peach</option>
  <option disabled selected value="6" class="bold-option">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have multiple vars (Subjects) for the Mango. So JQuery should read these out and place them under Mango, these are all different by name (subject). For example 
 {'subject': 'This is a mango'}
 {'subject': 'Hello There'}
 {'subject': 'Example'}
These should all be added beneath the Mango.